# Pronunciation of 締 in 月末締／翌月末払

Tags: readings, business-japanese

If I understood well, 月末締／翌月末払 means "close the deal before end of a given month then get payment before end of the following month"

Is the pronunciation "げつまつしめ　よくげつはらい"

I am especially unsure about 締 and the い for 払.

Comment: Is it 翌月払 or 翌月末払?

Comment: Yes I thought that too, I think I often hear 翌月払(い).

Answer (score 4):

I think it's...げつまつしめ、よくげつまつばらい.

Answer (score 4):

I would read it as げつまつじめ、よくげつまつばらい.  I was surprised to see that Chocolate reads 月末締 as げつまつしめ, but I suppose that it is either personal or dialectal difference.

Okurigana of a noun such as め in 締め and い in 払い is sometimes omitted, especially when the word is used as part of a compound word.

Comment: Hehe I'm getting less and less confident now...

Comment: I would also read it as げつまつじめ, but rendaku is often optional.